# Using WordPress account on a domain?

Tags: wordpress, blog

I just got my own domain from SiteGround (first time doing anything like this.) and installed WordPress on it.

Is it possible I could use that as my main WordPress account? I'm not seeing any option to follow other blogs, I don't see the "reader" and I'm pretty sure my account on this domain isn't actually visible on WordPress itself.

Alternatively, how do you go about following/subscribing to blogs that are connected through WordPress but are on their own domain with no option to follow on the WordPress system itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing WordPress on your own domain is possible with **wordpress.org**, like you did. Blogs hosted on **wordpress.com** are completely independent. so **wordpress.org** is not capable of connecting to blogs on **wordpress.com**, so it's not possible to follow, subscribe, etc. to blogs on **wordpress.com**.

Comment: Okay. So having a website built on .org isn't really a blog - it's just a standalone website. Well is there any way to have some sort of subscription system that lets people receive updates or "follow" my website? Thanks.

Comment: @Rockett It is, but it's not connected to the .com network. There are many plugins for that. Take a look at the [repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) :)

Comment: @Rockett Specifically look into the Jetpack plugin for this purpose. William is mostly correct that self-hosted WordPress is completely independent from wordpress.com but you can link them together in certain ways via Jetpack.

Comment: @JCL1178 Yes, indeed, very good suggestion. Edit my answer if you'd like to add that.